# Bind subset of collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an `ObservableCollection<Person>` object. The `Person` objects have `Name` and `Type` properties, where `Type` is either `student` or `teacher`. Is there any way to bind a `ComboBox` to a subset of the `ObservableCollection<Person>` object, where the `Type` property is only `teacher`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programatically as follows:

```
MyComboBox.ItemsSource = a.Where((obj, r) => { return (obj.Type == "student"); }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the cleanest and most obvious way to filter from what I can tell.

Answer (score 8):

`ICollectionView` is your answer here -

```
public ICollectionView Teachers
{
   get
   {
      // Persons is your ObservableCollection<Person>.
      var teachers = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Persons);
      teachers.Filter = p => (p as Person).Type == "Teacher";
      return teachers;
   }
}
```

You can bind your comboBox ItemSource with this property. When any item is added or removed from your source collection, this collection will be filtered automatically..

Comment: I'm a little late to the party but little typo : `var teachers` should be `var source`

Comment: @MickaelV. - Thanks.. Updated..!!

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

[WPF Binding to a Combo using only a subset of a Collection's items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875763/wpf-binding-to-a-combo-using-only-a-subset-of-a-collections-items)

Here are mentioned concepts like CollectionViewSource, Filters ecc...

Have a look also at

[Data bind to a portion of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265449/data-bind-to-a-portion-of-a-collection)

Comment: Thanks, there are some good information and links from those two questions.