# WPF Binding filtered ObservableCollection ICollectionView to Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, observablecollection, icollectionview

I want to filter an ObservableCollection to a subset based on type (type AddPoint) and want it ordered ascending with no duplicates.  My base class is ModelBase, w/ sub-classes AddPoint, Time, Repeat, etc...  The ObservableCollection MotionSequenceCollection will be filled w/ those types in any order and some will be duplicates.

I've tried several different times and shown them below in the ICollectionView Property that I 'pulled' from:  [Bind subset of collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621393/bind-subset-of-collection).

OBSERVABLE COLLECTION

```
private ObservableCollection<ModelBase> _motionSequenceCollection = 
        new ObservableCollection<ModelBase>();

    public ObservableCollection<ModelBase> MotionSequenceCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _motionSequenceCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_motionSequenceCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _motionSequenceCollection;
            _motionSequenceCollection = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICollectionView Location
    {
        get
        {
             var location = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_motionSequenceCollection);

            //DOES NOT WORK.  PROBLEM: GetType() creates type of system.type() and AddPoint, which don't work.  Need a cast, or something??  
            // found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621393/bind-subset-of-collection  The problem is that there is an error:
            //    Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'System.Type' and 'MotionSeq.Model.AddPoint',
            //    candidates are:
            //          bool ==(System.Reflection.MemberInfo, System.Reflection.memberInfo) (in class MemberInfo)
            //          bool ==(System.type, System.Type) (in class Type)
            //location.Filter = p => (p as ModelBase).GetType() == AddPoint;

            //DOES NOT WORK.  PROBLEM: Affects the main collection and won't let TIME type added.
            //location.Filter = o1 => (o1 is AddPoint);

            //DOES NOT WORK.  PROBLEM: Sorts fine, but also sorts MotionSequenceCollection!!  What up w/ that!?  
            //location.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("AddPointClassName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            //DOES NOT WORK.  PROBLEM: MotionSequenceCollection does not update.
            //location.Filter = p => (p as ModelBase) == AddPoint;

            //DOES NOT WORK.  PROBLEM: Source is not instantiated(?) and exmaple from stackoverflow and not sure how that got there in the first place.
            //source.Filter = p => (p as ModelBase).GetType() == "AddPoint";
            //return source;

            return location;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All collections have a default CollectionView. WPF always binds to a view rather than a collection. If you bind directly to a collection, WPF actually binds to the default view for that collection. This default view is shared by all bindings to the collection, which causes all direct bindings to the collection to share the sort, filter, group, and current item characteristics of the one default view.

try creating [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) and setting its filtering logic like this:

```
//create it as static resource and bind your ItemsControl to it
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="csv" Source="{StaticResource MotionSequenceCollection}" 
                  Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
       <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="YYY"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="YYY" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource> 

private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var t = e.Item as ModelBase;
    if (t != null)

    {
        //use your filtering logic here

    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm struggling massively with this.  I originally went @makc's way w/ the CollectionViewSource_FIlter and found a few examples to help, but the problem was with making the list distinct() - it was 2 days ago and my head is foggy.  The filter is like this:

Comment: I need to revise my comment.  I did get your solution working and  Learned a lot about collectionviewsource..  The problem is that if there are duplicates and only one shows in the combobox (filtered view), when I edit one in the collection, it does not update by adding the newly edited record.  If there is only one, then that updates as expected after propertychanged.   That's why I went down a linq path after, but that has proven to be disastrous.

Comment: @FloppyDisk I am very glad that you didnt just copy past but read and learned :), I am not sure I understand the problem completely try creating a small stand alone example and I think it's worth a new question...

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by type is easy. This should work:

```
location.Filter = p => p.GetType() == typeof(AddPoint);
```

Sorting is also quite easy. All you need to do is to implement `IComparer` and assign it to `CustomSort` property of collection view.

There is no easy way to remove duplicates tho (not that i am aware of). I suggest you to do it elsewhere. For example, you could distinct your underlying collection.

Comment: I changed my tack and tried to create a subset of an observablecollection with LINQ.  Then bind that back to my view.  It has been a serious run-around.  I do have an error that says I need to implement IComparer.  Looking into that.  Thanks for the response.